# find_by_sql and single quotes in an ORDER BY clause

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Rails 2.3.5

I know I should be doing find_by_sql with sanatized variables like:

```
sql = %Q{
SELECT blah
FROM blah
ORDER BY ? DESC
      }
```

But, since the variable will be single quoted, the ORDER BY clause won't work.   I know that un-sanitized I could just do:

```
sql = %Q{
SELECT blah
FROM blah
ORDER BY #{params[:sort]} DESC
      }
```

What's the best way to handle needing a sanatized varialbe in an ORDER BY clause?   Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe a little hack but i escape params sometimes like this.

```
sql = AnyActiveRecordModel.send(:sanitize_sql_array, ["SELECT blah FROM blah ORDER BY ? DESC", params[:sort])
```

sanitize_sql_array is a private class method of an active record model and like this you can access it. It is the same method which is used in the conditions in a AR find

```
AnyActiveRecordModel.find(:all, :conditions => ["condition = ?",params[:blah]]
```

It is dirty but i didnt know to solve it in a better way and I had a time limit :P

Comment: In rails 4.0.0, `send(:sanitize_sql_array, ["SELECT id FROM test_classes ORDER BY ? desc", "foo"])` results in `"SELECT id from test_classes ORDER BY 'foo' desc"`

Answer (score 0):

You can do your own sanitizing.  Something along the lines of

```
field = [column_names & [params[:field]]].first
#or field = column_names.detect{|name| name == params[:field]}, etc

direction = (%w[ASC DESC USING] & [params[:order].upcase]).first

"ORDER BY #{field} #{direction}"
```